# http connection error code from client server

Tags: http, networking, https, wireshark

We have multiple clients running worldwide. Connecting the nearest respective server as per country preference.

Now my primary requirement is, independent on client and server, with the help of networking information (logged in Wireshark), is it possible to retrieve HTTP status code.

For example, 404 Not Found if nothing available at the server-side.

I want to prompt error codes to the client indicating the reason for the disconnection.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already captured HTTP data on Wireshark you can just use the following filter to catch all response codes:

```
http.response.code == 404
```

For all response codes regardless:

```
http.response.code
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can open the .pcapng file and then

•   Click on “Statistics”

•   Select “HTTP”

•   Select “Packet Counter“

[image]

In my case, I can 14 requests and 14 responses. (Success 2xx).

[image]